# Graph coloring with CVXPY set up constraints

Tags: python-3.x, linear-programming, constraint-programming, cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to code the constraints for the graph coloring problem using CVXPY.  I am pretty new to mixed-integer programming (MIP), and I am having some difficulty specifying the constraints.  I have input data like the “edges” list below.  Where each tuple in the list is an edge that starts on one node and ends on the other.  For example the first edge starts on node “0” and ends on node “1”.

The constraints I would like to specify are:

- each node can have only one color.
- vertices sharing one edge should have different colors.
- each node must have at least one color.

The objective function would be the number of colors used.

For a selection variable I want to specify the color each node takes.

I’m using the `colors` array to multiply with the selection variable and then sum for each node, to select the color for the node and specify that each node can only have one color.

I’m getting the error below.  Am I constructing the selection variable correctly?

Also this seems like a lot of work, does anyone see a simpler way to do this?  Or does anyone know of an example of solving the graph coloring problem with CVXPY?

One more thing, if I transpose the colors array the error goes away.

Input data:

edges

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

code:

```
# selection variable
# 4 is the number of nodes
selection = cvxpy.Variable(4, boolean=True)

# array for colors
colors = np.array([[1,0,0,0],
                        [0,1,0,0],
                        [0,0,1,0],
                        [0,0,0,1],
                        [1,1,0,0],
                        [1,1,1,0],
                        [1,1,1,1],
                        [0,1,1,1],
                        [0,0,1,1],
                        [1,0,1,0],
                        [0,1,0,1],
                        [0,1,1,0],
                        [1,1,0,0],
                        [0,0,0,0]])


# each node can only have one color constraint

one_color = cvxpy.sum(selection * colors, axis=0) == 1
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b22226c89a2f> in <module>()
      1 # each node can only have one color constraint
      2 
----> 3 one_color = cvxpy.sum(selection * colors, axis=0) == 1

~/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/expressions/expression.py in cast_op(self, other)
     47         """
     48         other = self.cast_to_const(other)
---> 49         return binary_op(self, other)
     50     return cast_op
     51 

~/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/expressions/expression.py in __mul__(self, other)
    385             return cvxtypes.multiply_expr()(self, other)
    386         elif self.is_constant() or other.is_constant():
--> 387             return cvxtypes.mul_expr()(self, other)
    388         else:
    389             warnings.warn("Forming a nonconvex expression.")

~/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/atoms/affine/binary_operators.py in __init__(self, lh_exp, rh_exp)
     41 
     42     def __init__(self, lh_exp, rh_exp):
---> 43         super(BinaryOperator, self).__init__(lh_exp, rh_exp)
     44 
     45     def name(self):

~/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/atoms/atom.py in __init__(self, *args)
     42         self.args = [Atom.cast_to_const(arg) for arg in args]
     43         self.validate_arguments()
---> 44         self._shape = self.shape_from_args()
     45         if len(self._shape) > 2:
     46             raise ValueError("Atoms must be at most 2D.")

~/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/atoms/affine/binary_operators.py in shape_from_args(self)
    107         """Returns the (row, col) shape of the expression.
    108         """
--> 109         return u.shape.mul_shapes(self.args[0].shape, self.args[1].shape)
    110 
    111     def is_atom_convex(self):

~/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/utilities/shape.py in mul_shapes(lh_shape, rh_shape)
    140     lh_old = lh_shape
    141     rh_old = rh_shape
--> 142     lh_shape, rh_shape, shape = mul_shapes_promote(lh_shape, rh_shape)
    143     if lh_shape != lh_old:
    144         shape = shape[1:]

~/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/utilities/shape.py in mul_shapes_promote(lh_shape, rh_shape)
    107     if lh_mat_shape[1] != rh_mat_shape[0]:
    108         raise ValueError("Incompatible dimensions %s %s" % (
--> 109             lh_shape, rh_shape))
    110     if lh_shape[:-2] != rh_shape[:-2]:
    111         raise ValueError("Incompatible dimensions %s %s" % (

ValueError: Incompatible dimensions (1, 4) (14, 4)
```

Comment: The message is quite good `Incompatible dimensions (1, 4) (14, 4)`  You should interpret `selection * colors` as a matrix multiplication.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  So should I transpose the colors array?  That gets rid of the error.  Also am I setting up the selection variable correctly?  Since I can't print the selection variable it's a little unclear to me how it works.  My goal is to be able to select the color of the node, and then construct the rest of the constraints later.

Comment: Transposing seems right to me. You can also set the shape explicitly when creating the variables. See the CVXPY documentation for details.